# Micrornaut. Logger configuration for an environment

Tags: spring-boot, micronaut

I'm trying out the micronaut-framework (1.0.1) and wondering whether there is a possibility to configure some logger for a cerntain environment like I did it in spring boot:
I.e for the environment (profile) `prod` I wannt this logger configuration. 
`application-prod.yaml:`

```
logging:
  level:
    root: warn
    xyz.x: info
    xyz.x.processorcli.ProcessorCliApplication: warn
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a workaround.
In Micronaut you can override location of your logback.xml by setting the system property `logback.configurationFile`. I.e. `java -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback-prod.xml -jar your.jar`

Comment: A correction, it is a [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty) property not micronaut's